# Can Storable store to the DATA filehandle?

Tags: perl, storable

I was curious if using [Storable](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.8/Storable.html)'s store_fd and fd_retrieve would allow me to store a data structure into a program's own DATA filehandle. I realize this isn't Best Practice, I'm just curious if it'd work, my quick attempts to try it don't seem to work.

Comment: I would expect to fd_retreive to work, and store_fd to fail.

Comment: What purpose do you have in mind?

Comment: DATA is usually only open for input; try Inline::Files?

Comment: The purpose is simply to see If Perl Can. It simply for amusements sake.
From the comments I understand that `DATA` cannot be written to?

Comment: * That would explain the hoops Inline::File jumps through to write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you'd want to do that, but you can fake it. You should try to avoid that though.

Just for giggles, you could open a filehandle, read lines from `$0` and print them until you get to `__DATA__`, then add your new `__DATA__` section. The trick is then to rename your new file to become `$0`, perhaps by an `exec` if your system locks the file while the program is running:

```
#!perl

my $mode = (stat($0))[2] & 07777;

open my($fh), '<', $0 or die "I can't open me! $!\n";
open my($new), '>', "$0.new" or die "I can't open you! $!\n";
eval { chmod( $mode, $new ) } or warn "Couldn't set permissions: $@\n";

while( <$fh> )
    {
    last if /^__DATA__$/;
    print { $new } $_;
    }

print "I am $$\n";
print { $new } "__DATA__\n", join '|', $$, time, (stat($0))[1];

rename( "$0.new", $0 )

__DATA__
64574|1265415126|8843292
```

Answer (score 1):

`DATA` is a handle to *read* data stored with the script. Conway's [Inline::Files](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Inline::Files) is the only module I know offhand that talks of *writable* virtual files. And since script files are usually ASCII I don't know what would happen if you got a binary 26 byte on MSDOS or a binary 4 on UNIX in the output of Storable.

However, if you are talking about *you* storing data by *typing* it in there, only to *read* it from a script, then the binary problem still confronts you.

So, it's better to go with [YAML](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?YAML) or [JSON](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JSON) for persistence. I know that YAML will handle the blessing when retrieving the data from DATA.

Comment: `binmode(__DATA__)` i imagine

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible in ordinary conditions:

```
$ cat write-data
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
print DATA "bar!\n";

$ ./write-data
Name "main::DATA" used only once: possible typo at ./write-data line 6.
print() on unopened filehandle DATA at ./write-data line 6.
```

But you can create extraordinary conditions:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use Data::Dumper;
use File::Temp qw/ tempfile /;
use Storable qw/ store_fd fd_retrieve /;

sub store_in_DATA {
  my($data) = @_;

  my($fh,$path) = tempfile;
  unlink $path           or warn "$0: unlink: $!";

  *DATA = $fh;
  store_fd $data, \*DATA or warn "$0: print: $!";

  seek DATA, 0, 0        or warn "$0: seek: $!";
}

store_in_DATA { foo => "There is no spoon.\n" };

undef $/;
my $ref = fd_retrieve \*DATA;
print Dumper $ref;
```

On Windows, you'll get a warning on the `unlink` because of its default file-sharing semantics. If that's your platform, you can clean up at `END` time or use [Win32::SharedFileOpen](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Win32-SharedFileOpen/lib/Win32/SharedFileOpen.pm).

Answer (score 0):

I came up with my own solution... not that I specifically recommend it or any others; in my case it's a unit test script with reference values in a multi-dimensional hash structure. I won't go into the technical details of what this things does and why, but the end result is that a small fix or change in the code can result in many values requiring an update (after validating the change is valid).

Therefore I moved the hash into the `__DATA__` section using `Data::Dumper`. The code to write that to a file handle looks like:

```
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Terse = 1; # to Eval whole thing as a hash
$Data::Dumper::Indent = 1; # Looks better, just a preference
$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1; # To keep changes minimal in source control
print $fh Dumper(\%HASH);
```

At the beginning of the script I load the hash from `DATA` after storing references to the initial handle's position and mtime (mtime is used to ensure the file hasn't been modified during the script's execution).

```
use vars qw(%HASH $FILEPOS $MTIME);

{
    $FILEPOS = tell(DATA);
    $MTIME = (stat(DATA))[9];
    local $/;
    my $data = <DATA>;
    %HASH = %{eval $data};
}
```

Finally, to update the `__DATA__` section I open `__FILE__` at `$FILEPOS`, truncate it and write to it. I simplified error handling for this example.

```
open(my $fh, '>>', __FILE__) or die $!;
seek($fh, $FILEPOS, 0) or die $!;
die "File changed" if ((stat($fh))[9] != $MTIME);
truncate($fh, $FILEPOS) or die $!;

# Assumes Dumper is already loaded and configured as in first code snippet
print $fh Dumper(\%HASH);
```

Be sure to keep backups of your files as you develop as a single mistake could destroy all your code!

Also note that the same would work with `Storable`; storage would be more efficient and faster. The only caveat is that it's binary, which means file diff will likely not show up in source control, and it's not as easy to edit as Dumper's output.